# Gradient descent parameter estimation Package for R

Tags: r, gradient-descent

I am looking for a package that does gradient descent parameter estimation in R, maybe with some bootstrapping to get confidence intervals. I wonder if people call it something different here as I get almost nothing on my searches, and the one article I found was from someone who rolled their own.

It is not that hard to implement, but I would prefer to use something standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of looking I found the "optim" routine which is in "stats", one of the packages that is always loaded. It has quite a few methods including conjugate gradients and BGGS and a few others and worked well on the first few examples I tried. It doesn't seem to get a lot of attention strangely. I guess optimization people tend to use Matlab.

I knew there had to be something.